# Handle windows Alert..(electron base desktop application) in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, electron, build-automation, awtrobot, sikuli-script

I am automating desktop application. The application is base on an electron so I can easy to get XPATH and other things like a web application. But I am stuck on windows alert.

I am trying a robot class. but a key event not supporting in electron base application.

```
robot.keypress(keyevent.vk_enter)
robot.keyrelease(keyevent.vk_enter)
```

I am trying normal selenium web driver code to handle pop but selenium does not support windows popup.

I am trying to AutoIT tools. with this code

```
ControlFocus("petpooja","","Button1")
ControlClick("petpooja","","Button1")
```

and this code

```
SEND("{ENTER}")
```

With this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".\\Driver\\autoitpath\\EnterPopUp.exe");
```

I am also trying to use Sikuli but that also not supporting.

```
public Screen s = new Screen();
s.click("./Driver/Image/Popup.PNG");
```

Please help me guys on this I also attached the image please refer to this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxGtX.png)